# Deploying Django project on EC2 with BitNami image

Tags: python, django, deployment, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a complex university project that requires building some specific libraries and the use of threads (AppEngine out of the question), and I want to deploy in on EC2 (Free tier deal).

I was wondering what would be best, to start with a bare linux distribution or the BitNami Django stack ?

I've seen similar questions here, but I'm looking for Pro's and Con's mainly.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is pretty obvious. If you start with the Bitnami stack you'll save yourself the hassle of installing and configuring the various components (web server, gateway, python and the required libs, DB, etc.).

So if you app is pretty straight forward (typical web app) then sure, start with the bitnami stack. At most you'll reconfigure certain parts later on, as needed.

There's no particular joy in installing and configuring it all yourself, imo.